# Can OSX VPN into my work environment with forticlient?

Tags: macos, vpn

My work suggests we use forticlient to VPN into our workstations.

Is it possible to use the built-in VPN client in OSX to do the same thing?  I have the latest mojave version installed.

Comment: Why don't (can't?) you use the official client?

Comment: I don't want to install 3rd party software for no reason...I'm a minimalist :)

Answer (score 1):

In my brief examination of forticlient, it seems like forticlient uses a proprietary connection set up protocol. This is not plain old OpenVPN with preshared keys. It is theoretically possible to reverse engineer the client, but that is an incredible amount of work for not wanting to install 3rd party software. Just use the official client.